# Python - TypeError: an integer is required (filter function)

Tags: python-2.7, list, filter

I am trying to create a function that will return a list of word that start with the letter "p". I am getting a "TypeError: an integer is required" error. I am not sure where an integer is required, or why.

```
def filter_words(word_list, letter):
    return filter(list().pop([0]) == letter, word_list)

filter_words(["banana", "apple", "pear", "grapefruit", "pineapple",\
"orange", "plum", "kiwi"], "p")
```

The output I am going for is ["pear", "pineapple", "plum"].

Thank you so much!

Comment: Isn't the first argument to `filter` a function? Doesn't match the error you're getting, but I can't figure out how your code is supposed to work.

Comment: the error you get is from the pop method, it need at integer argument, not a list, and even if you fix that you will get other errors, and that without mention that the first argument of filter need to be a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what your intent was with the first argument of `filter`. Filter requires a function as it's first argument, where the argument passed is each item in the list (the words in this case). This is a version that works for me:

```
def filter_words(word_list, letter):
    return filter(lambda word: word[0] == letter, word_list)

print(filter_words(["banana", "apple", "pear", "grapefruit", "pineapple",\
"orange", "plum", "kiwi"], "p"))
```

Note how the first argument is a function (lambda) that accepts a word and checks its first letter.

Also note, I rarely ever write Python, and wrote this on my phone quickly on my break, so there may be better ways to write this. This will break on empty words since they don't have a 0th character. It should give you an idea of how `filter` works though.

Comment: Yes, this works great. I guess I was thinking that list was my function, but this makes more sense. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @noob112358 Np. If it answers your question, you can accept it to say that it's resolved, and upvote if it helped you.